# Display component data from nested routes - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following components:

TodosComponent (path: './todos/'): with html content `<p>TODO WORKS</p>`

AddTodosComponent (path: './todos/add'): with html content `<p>ADD TODO WORKS</p>`

DeleteTodosComponent (path: './todos/delete'): with html content `<p>DELETE TODO WORKS</p>`

Add and Delete are nested routes in Todos.

In my main AppComponent I have a sidenav with links for the 3 components (TodosComponent, AddTodosComponent, DeleteTodosComponent).

I am trying to display in the content area of AppComponent the contents of the 3 components whenever one is clicked from the sidenav.
**When I click the child routes I am receiving this error:  *Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'todos/add'***

**How can I display in sidenav-content from AppComponent the html from the components when a link is clicked in the sidenav?**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/todos', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'todos', component: TodosComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
    { path: 'add', component: AddTodoComponent},
    { path: 'delete', component: DeleteTodoComponent},
  ]},
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav opened="true" mode="side" fixedInViewport="true">
    <p>I am the sidenav</p>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item>
        <a matLine routerLink="/todos">List Todos</a>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <a matLine routerLink="/todos/add">Add Todo</a>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <a matLine routerLink="/todos/delete">Delete Todo</a>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <p>Main Content</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

What I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: can you try removing `pathMatch: 'full'` from the `/todos` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

> Technically, pathMatch = 'full' results in a route hit when the
>   remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match ''.

In your example, at the path `todos`, the remaining, unmatched part is `/todos/add`, which is not an exact match, and the router won't look the children inside that and skip to the next path (which you don't have any) and when none found, you get the error you are getting :)

Remove `pathMatch: 'full'` from `/todos` path and it should work:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/todos', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'todos', component: TodosComponent,  children: [
    { path: 'add', component: AddTodoComponent},
    { path: 'delete', component: DeleteTodoComponent},
  ]},
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why we need children, as we are displaying all in the same router-outlet.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/todos', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '/todos', component: TodosComponent }, 
  { path: '/todos/add', component: AddTodoComponent },
  { path: '/todos/delete', component: DeleteTodoComponent }
]
```